# How do you prepare and grill blackened salmon?

Tags: grilling, fish, salmon

I've never grilled blackened salmon before, but is there anything more involved than simply sprinkling blackened seasoning on both sides and grilling it for 5-7 minutes on each side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's all there is to it. It seems you already know this, but just to be sure, be aware that "blackened" refers to the spice and not any burning or charring that is done. Burnt spices taste horrendous.

Comment: thanks for the note on "blackened."  I was actually not sure what blackened meant exactly, so thanks for the clarificaiton.  Do I need to oil to the salmon to get the seasoning to "stick" before throwing it on the grill?

Comment: No you don't need to. I've seen recipes that direct you to oil/butter the steaks/filets before spicing, and ones that just go with a dry rub. I personally do mine dry.

Comment: What would you put in your spice mix?  I'd go ground black pepper, salt, paprika, cumin, and coriander. Or black pepper, salt, ginger, cayenne, and clove.  Or...

Comment: Should't you dry it before grill?